# Master theorem for recurrences without f(n)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, big-o, master-theorem

can Master theorem be applied to the recurrences in which f(n) is zero for example: `T(n)=2T(n/3) + 0`? If yes how will it be solved? will it take constant time given that `T(1)=1`?

Comment: Can you solve for n=3^k?

Comment: @PaulHankin we are to derive a generalized expression in terms of n.

Comment: It's expected that you put some work into answering the question before asking it here. My comment was a suggestion about a simple case that you could investigate, and maybe see "if it take constant time given that T(1)=1". Given that simple case, you may be able to produce the formula for general n -- in much the same way that for example merge sort is often studied for powers-of-two sized arrays initially.

Comment: @PaulHankin I understand  your concern. I am working on the same from hours. But here I am stuck at the fundamentals which only one who actually knows what to do(according to norms in such exceptional case) can answer. Directly finding its complexity is a different thing, but I wanted to understand what master methods says about dealing with such case. Its cause of worry when people who didnt get the essence of question just simply down vote it, so even others cant see it. They could probably overlook it and at least let other people who have enough knowledge n zeal to answer it do their work.

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n)=2T(n/3) + 0
```

a = 2, b =3, c = 0 because we looking for n<sup>c</sup>,since we have zero as a constant so that only n<sup>0</sup> can be used here. so T(n) is bounded by n<sup>log<sub>3</sub>2</sup>, approx. n<sup>0.63</sup>.

Comment: Using n<sup>0</sup> for 0 seems wrong because former means that for every recursion step its taking constant amount of time while later(as in our case) which is 0 means we are doing "no extra work" in each recursion step. So why doesnt it takes just constant amount of time to execute. This was the basic doubt.

Comment: Yes. but keep in mind that 0 has a upperbound of O(1), which is constant. So regardless of whether you have a zero or a non-zero constant, T(n) will still be bounded by n^log(3)2. If you want to find the exact running time of T with respect to n, then you better off solving the recurrence relation than applying the Master's Theorem.